# Why is instead of trigger allowing row insert

Tags: sql, t-sql

Trying to figure out why the trigger allows the insert of row into seating table when the number of guests exceeds the number of seats. This is a single row level trigger that i'm experimenting with and self teaching with help from SO.

```
create table dining_table
(
table_id                int             not null,
area_id                 int             not null,
table_seats             int             not null

constraint PK_dining_table primary key(table_id),
constraint FK_dining_table_table_area foreign key(area_id)
    references table_area(area_id)
);

insert into dining_table(table_id, area_id, table_seats)
values(1, 1, 2);
insert into dining_table(table_id, area_id, table_seats)
values(2, 2, 4);

create table customers
(
customer_id             int             not nulL,
cust_lastname           varchar(50)     not null,
cust_total_guests       int             not null,

constraint PK_customers primary key(customer_id)
);

insert into customers(customer_id, cust_lastname, cust_total_guests)
values(1, 'Wallman', 4);
insert into customers(customer_id, cust_lastname, cust_total_guests)
values(2, 'Griffin', 6);


create table seating
(
customer_id             int             not null,
table_id                int             not null,
seat_cost               decimal(10,2)   not null,
seat_date               datetime        not null,
tip_amount              decimal(10,2)   not null,

constraint PK_seating primary key(customer_id, table_id)    
);

insert into seating(customer_id, table_id, seat_cost, seat_date,   
tip_amount)
values(1, 1, 15.00, '20170506', 5.00);
insert into seating(customer_id, table_id, seat_cost, seat_date, 
tip_amount)
values(2, 2, 35.50, '20170608', 11.00);
```

Trigger:

```
if OBJECT_ID('seats_available','U') is not null
drop trigger seats_available;
go

create trigger seats_available
on dbo.seating
instead of insert 
as
begin
    insert into seating
    select *
    from inserted
    where exists (select dt.table_seats 
                  from dining_table dt
                  join seating s on dt.table_id = s.table_id
                  join customers c on s.customer_id = c.customer_id
                  where dt.table_seats >= c.cust_total_guests)
end
go
--test trigger

insert into seating(customer_id, table_id, seat_cost, seat_date,  
tip_amount)
values(2, 1, 25.00, GETDATE(), 3.00);



values(2, 2, 35.50, '20170608', 11.00);
```

Comment: Odd that your `exists` subquery doesn't reference `inserted`. As long as there is _any_ table with seats greater _or equal_ to the guests the `insert` can proceed.

Comment: *This is a single row level trigger* **Wrong**. There is no such thing in sql server. Triggers are fired based on statements, not on rows. This means that the `inserted` table may contain more than one row.

Comment: The question re-worded should be 'why does the insert statement execute?' The statement should not execute. There are not enough seats available for this customer who has 6 total guests and the table has 4 seats.

Comment: starting to think the example from the book has a misprint.